# CSS selector attr *= support in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors, selectivizr

I noticed selectivizr does not support [attr*=] using jQuery.

Any ideas on how I could support the following selector in ie8?

```
a:not([class*="st-"])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `:not()` is a problem here too.

Comment: Right, but selectivizr will help with :not

Comment: Apprently, selectivizr says a library like MooTools would support it, but obviously i'm not switching libraries. Maybe I'll have to do it with pure js...

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp):

> Note: IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector.

I believe that's the only bit that doesn't work in IE8.

> [The [attribute*=value] selector is supported in all major browsers.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp)
>
> **Note:** For this selector to work in IE8 and earlier, a `<!DOCTYPE>` must be declared.

So if you have Selectivizr to fix the `:not()` part, I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Right, but selectivizr will help with :not

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment. Also http://caniuse.com is a much better resource for browser support.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I felt like it was the only real valid answer. Only other thing he could have done is show *how* to get Selectivizr to fix the `:not()` part.

Comment: @VoidKing he has edited the answer since. This was the original: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a356bf94-0c66-4efe-9a31-ac1f6cae554a/view-source